# Can I use unity-greeter in elementary OS?

Tags: greeter

Is it safe to change the elementary OS Luna/Freya login screen (`pantheon-greeter`) to Ubuntu's LightDM `unity-greeter`?

Comment: I figured it out.   And unity-greeter doesn't look so good with elementary OS freya (64bit)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe. 
But there is a possible risk of accidentally corrupting the main environment so i would recommend to leave any files you don't know about alone.